# Creating a CSV File in C#

Tags: c#, csv

I am trying to created a csv file where each entry is inputed by the user. Once one set of of values have been entered it should move on to the next. However I cannot seem to do the bit. Each time i run the program, it replaces the previous values.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;


namespace FileAccess
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string FName;
            string LName;
            string Dpt;
            string Grade;
            string NumberOfHours;

            string file_name = "EmployeeDetails.txt";

            System.IO.StreamWriter objWriter;
            objWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(file_name);

            String[] ArrayDetails = new string[5];

            Console.Write("Enter Emp First Name: ");
            FName=Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Enter Emp Last Name: ");
            LName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Enter Emp Department: ");
            Dpt = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Enter Employee Grade: ");
            Grade = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Enter Number Of Hours Worked: ");
            NumberOfHours = Console.ReadLine();

            ArrayDetails[0] = FName;
            ArrayDetails[1] = LName;
            ArrayDetails[2] = Dpt;
            ArrayDetails[3] = Grade;
            ArrayDetails[4] = NumberOfHours;

            // Create new list of strings
            List<string> LDetails = new List<string>(); // Create new list of strings
            LDetails.Add(FName); // Add string 1
            LDetails.Add(LName); // 2
            LDetails.Add(Dpt); // 3
            LDetails.Add(Grade); // 4
            LDetails.Add(NumberOfHours); // 5
            //OutPut the data into the file
            string LDetailsCSV = string.Join(",", LDetails.ToArray());
            Console.WriteLine(LDetailsCSV);
            objWriter.Write(LDetailsCSV);
            objWriter.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Some advise please.

Comment: be aware that if any of the fields you are writing have commas in them, you'll need to add quotes around the field (and then escape any quotes in the field).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [StreamWriter constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fysy0a4b.aspx) will overwrite the file you are using if it exists.  There is an [overloaded constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb.aspx) to which you can pass a boolean as a second argument to tell it to append:

```
System.IO.StreamWriter objWriter;
objWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(file_name, true);
```

In addition, the [Write](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ce2kyyb4.aspx) method you are using will not append a line break.  If you use the [WriteLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ack4zyt.aspx) method, it will.

```
 Console.WriteLine(LDetailsCSV);
 objWriter.WriteLine(LDetailsCSV);
 objWriter.Close();
```

Comment: Thanks. This is almost what I want. But this does not create a new line.

Answer (score 9):

You have to open the file in append mode, like this:

```
System.IO.StreamWriter objWriter;
objWriter = new File.AppendText(file_name);
```

Answer (score 2):

In your case I think you are better off doing something like:

```
File.AppendAllText("EmployeeDetails.txt", string.Join(",",new [] {FName,LName,Dpt,Grade,NumberOfHours}));
```