# How would I write this to a csv file in c#?

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010, linq, xml-parsing

I hope someone can help me. I am a beginner at c# and programming in general and I'm trying to complete this program. Basically it looks in an XML file, grabs all of the occurrences of a specific tag and is supposed to write the File Names plus whatever is between any instances of these two tags. So far I've tried TextWriter, StreamWriter, FileStream and some others and nothing doing what I want. I realise this may be a stupid question but I'm a super noob and need help for my particular case. My code is as follows.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var files = from file in Directory.GetFiles("W:\\SRC\\hDefMl\\1.0\\Instrument_Files")
                    orderby file
                        ascending
                    select file;

        StringBuilder sb_report = new StringBuilder();

        string delimiter = ",";

        sb_report.AppendLine(string.Join(delimiter, "Module", "Generator(s)"));

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            string filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);

            Console.WriteLine("The HDefML file for {0} contains these EEPROM Generators:", filename);

            XDocument hdefml = XDocument.Load(file);

            var GeneratorNames = from b in hdefml.Descendants("Generators")
                                 select new
                                     {
                                         name = (string)b.Element("GeneratorName")
                                     };

            string description;

            foreach (var generator in GeneratorNames)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("   GeneratorName is: {0}", generator.name);
                sb_report.AppendLine(string.Join(delimiter, filename,
                generator.name));
            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly do you *want* it to do? TextWriter and StreamWriter are incredibly flexible ways of writing to a file.

Comment: There is an excellent lib "KentBoogard" that specializes writing CSV files.. check out

Comment: I want to write what the Console.WriteLine is writing basically to a csv file. I'm not doubting TextWriter or StreamWriter my not being able to use them as an example of my ineptitude/inexperience. @screenmutt

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671506/creating-a-csv-file-in-c-sharp

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed. I'd rather not use a 3rd party library, my project doesn't really warrant it.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just do something like this, if the string you have built with your string builder is formatted correctly.

```
    static void WriteToCSV(string str, string path)
    {
        using (Stream stream = File.Create(path))
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
        {
            writer.WriteLine(str);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry; what is str in this?

Comment: str is the contents of a .csv file, it seems like your building your string in the StringBuilder sb_report. So calling WriteToCSV(sb_report.ToString(), "test.csv"); will work if sb_report is in a correct .csv format.

Answer (score 0):

```
try{
    FileStream FS;
    StreamWriter SW;

    using (FS = new FileStream("HardCodedFileName.csv", FileMode.Append))
    {
        using (SW = new StreamWriter(FS))
        {
            foreach (var generator in GeneratorNames)
            {
                SW.WriteLine(string.Join(delimiter, filename,
                generator.name));
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e){
    Console.Writeline(e.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Just tack it on to what I have so far? @amalgamate

Comment: as a side note, you should wrap your FileStream and StreamWriters in "using statements" (as Zenchovey did), [here's why](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

Comment: replace your "foreach (var generator in GeneratorNames)" block except that I left out your Console.Writeline statement so you may want to add that back in.

Comment: @ry8806 Fair enough... I will revise... revised now.

Comment: @amalgamate when I use this all I get in my .csv is the name of the last file is the directory? Is something over-writing whatever is there before it?

Comment: btw: For those who followed along here, when I was previously using dispose it was necessary (I was not sure before) as the dispose would properly close the streams, if I only had it in the catch block which I did not. So a using block is definitely a better way to go.

Comment: @amalgamate it would appear each iteration over a new file is deleting the work of the last, the whole thing takes about three seconds.

Comment: @jason also revised to append just now.

Comment: @jason not sure weather it's doing exactly what you want. If you want everything to go into one file, then chose a file path that is different. I am choosing a different file for each file being read. With append you wouldn't have to do anything else to get there. With create you would have to extend the scope of the using blocks. For example :"using (FS = new FileStream("hardCodedFileName.csv", FileMode.Append))"

Comment: @amalgamate Oh okay, yeah I want 'em all in the same file. Thanks for the help.