# how to fetch multiple element from xml and write the value as csv

Tags: c#, xml

From the following xml, name Regression and smoke has to be fetched and written as Regression,Smoke in the output.

```
<categories>
        <category name="Regression" />
        <category name="Smoke" />
</categories>
```

Comment: Any luck with that? Are you using `System.Xml` or `System.Xml.Linq`?

Answer (score 0):

here is a scratch using linq to xml:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"<path to your xml file>");
var names = doc.Elements("category").Select(e => (string)e.Attribute("name"));
var csv = string.Join(",", names);
```

Answer (score 0):

if all that you want is to read your xml category name values and write them to a text file with comma as delimiter,  you should do this :

```
///step1: read all the elements attribute value
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var data = doc.Descendants("category")
                      .Select(s=>s.Attribute("name").Value)
                      .ToList();

///step2: write the read value to the file
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("d://csv.txt", true))
{
    writer.WriteLine(string.Join(",", data));
}
//or simply
//File.WriteAllText("d://csv.txt", string.Join(",", data));
```

and if you want to create a standard CSV file with proper headers and everything, you can find plenty of code, most of them here in SO, to do this. have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671506/creating-a-csv-file-in-c-sharp)

Comment: why not `File.WriteAllLines`?

Comment: because WriteAllLines will write each item in a new line, and OP simply needs comma separated values. However, yeah, using System.IO.File is neat

Comment: :), you are right, but read the question i.e. `fetched and written as Regression,Smoke`

Comment: Why 2 full iterations in .ToList() and string.Join?